# Why is this code removing the original value of remove duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

This code is to remove duplicate and divide the value each 500 cells, but for example if i run this code with only A1:A500 = 1 it will remove the 1 too.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim lr As Long, i As Long, c As Long
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A:A")
        rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    c = 2
For i = 501 To lr Step 500
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, c), ws.Cells(500, c)).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i + 500, 1)).Value
    c = c + 1
Next i
ws.Range("A501:A" & lr).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: That's because `lr` is equal to `1`. The last row is equal to `1` after you remove duplicates. Therefore, row `1` is cleared with `ws.Range("A501:A" & lr).ClearContents`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for the explanation of it, but still don't know what do I have to change to fix it, can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do to be honest. The comment was just explaining the reason why.

Comment: @BigBen On the example, if I write the same number until the row 500 will delete it and wont keep it, that's what im trying to fix

Comment: Well you could for example do `ws.Range("A501:A" & lr + 1).ClearContents`, but I don't know if that's what you actually want to do.

Comment: @BigBen That fixed it. Thank you, can you do a explain me a little bit about that +1? .

Comment: That's what my first comment was. `lr` in this case is equal to `1`. So you're clearing the first cell.